# What does Error-code 0xc0000135 (or -1073741515 Exit-code) mean when starting a Windows app?

Tags: .net, windows, dll, dependencies, exit-code

Symptom is that the .NET application starts correctly on the majority of PCs (Windows 7 and XP) at the user's site, but on one machine it consistently fails to start with the error "The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0000135)". What's the issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This error is caused when the .NET framework is not installed on the target computer, or when the version(s) installed are not sufficient to run the application. The resolution is obvious: install the correct version of the .NET framework before running the application.

Answer (score 26):

From the ntstatus.h SDK header file:

```
//
// MessageId: STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND
//
// MessageText:
//
// The program can't start because %hs is missing from your computer. 
// Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
//
#define STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND             ((NTSTATUS)0xC0000135L)    // winnt
```

The "try reinstalling the program" advice is solid, it is however up to you to figure out exactly *what* needs to be installed.  The name in the message is often missing or is not a good lead because a DLL can't be loaded due to a missing dependency.

You need a utility that can trace LoadLibrary() calls, I recommend [SysInternals' ProcMon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) over the built-in "loader snaps" feature.  Towards the bottom of the displayed trace you'll see Windows searching for the missing DLL and failing to find it.  If it is mscoree.dll then you forgot to install .NET 3.5 on the target machine.

Comment: How did you manage to find this information (that this error code corresponds to this error)?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin I think it'd be enough to simply grep for the error code. I was able to do this even with Wine on Linux, using `grep -ir 0xc0000135 /usr/include/wine/` command

Comment: ntstatus.h is from the Windows SDK.  In general a goldmine of obscure information.  It documents the low-level OS errors, winerror.h has a list of runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

Also check the version, there is also a ".NET Framework 4.0", which is different from 3.5. The 4.0 will NOT run applications designed for 3.5