# undefined reference SDL_Init with Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I've already gone through questions similar to mine, but none solved my problem.
So I'm trying to use SDL in a Qt Widget (for educational purpose), and I always get and undefined reference on every SDL fonction that I call.

Here is the (minimalist) code I've been using for testing :

```
#include "mainview.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "SDL.h"
#undef main


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainView w;
    w.show();

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindowFrom((void*)w.centralWidget->winId());
    SDL_Renderer* render = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(render, 255, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(render, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(render);

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(render);
    SDL_Quit();
    return a.exec();


}
```

And here is th .pro file :

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2014-10-08T22:37:55
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = MapEditor
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainview.cpp

HEADERS  += mainview.h

FORMS    += mainview.ui

INCLUDEPATH += SDL/include/
LIBS += -L SDL/lib/x86/SDL2.lib
```

According to other answers i've read, it seems the problem comes from the link to the library.
I have never really used this file, or other qmake before, so I am not sure about the path I am using. I work on windows, and according to [this article](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs), I should be writing the full path, but then I get access authorization problems (damn Windows).
Furthermore, changing the path to an false one doesn't seems to upset the compiler. 
However, when I try to use

```
LIBS += -L SDL/lib/x86/ -lSDL2.lib
```

the compiler cannot find the file.
The compiler I'm using is a MinGW 32bits, so I've downloaded the corresponding file on lbsdb.org, and I've tried every library on very sub-folder there was (x86_64, i686,...) but none worked.

And sorry if the way I'm writing is strange, I'm french.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not at all familiar with Windows build environments, Qt, nor SDL, but here are two thoughts: if you specify the `-l<libname>` flag, the compiler (gcc-like on UNIX-like systems) will look for a `lib<libname>.ext` file in the library path. Your `SDL.lib` doesn't match that pattern. Second: `.lib` is, iirc, a static library extension. Have you tried simply specifying `LIBS += SDL/lib/x86/SDL2.lib`, without any `-l` or `-L` flags?

Comment: I tried, and I got "No such file or directory". I think the flag mean the path is relative. And i can't use absolute path since I get authorization problems.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a *.lib* file, it's easiest to just add the file for linker. You have it subdirectory of your project it seems, but you are probably using a separate build directory (as you should), so the problem is probably that. To fix, use [`PWD` *qmake* variable](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#pwd):

```
LIBS += $${PWD}/SDL/lib/x86/SDL2.lib
```

You might also want to add `PWD` to include path, because relative path there is relative to directory of the *.c* file, and you might not always have them all in the same directory.

---

In a comment you mention something about not being able to use absolute paths... Not sure what you mean by that, but then a way out is to not use shadow build (which is no problem, as long as you remember to do full rebuild when changing build types). If you are using Qt Creator, you can find the project's build settings for each build type under **Projects** view, and there you have a check box for shadow build.

Comment: I'm not sure about the build director, I'm not used to Qt, and I rarely go look into things like that right of the bat. Well, i didn't touch it, so if the default value is good, I'm good. Th good news is that it seems to works! At least it compile. The program crash with no output and no error message, but i don't think it comes from th same problem, unless using the wrong library can cause it.

Comment: Ok, now Qt is going crazy. I've been trying the exact same thing I've been doing until now and now Qt doesn't give me any compiler error, it just launch and crash. When I've tried to launch in Debug mode, i got the error window saying "During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135". Do I need to create a new subject for this?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11433714/1717300) might help with that error code: some DLL is not found. Do you have any extra DLLs in addition to normal Qt DLLs? Are you sure the SDL2 library is a static library? If you have a SDL2 DLL, then you can quickly test by copying it to the same dir with exe manually (not a proper solution, just to test if it's that DLL missing). If it is that DLL, then you could expand this question with details. If it's not, then you probably should ask a new question.