# Eclipse debugging error with 64 bits libXL

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-mars, libxl

When trying to debug this [Eclipse CDT Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1dS7bWX63QZX0d5Z21WOVg5M2s/view?usp=sharing) compiled with Mingw-w64 ([build-info.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1dS7bWX63QZamdQaW1nR0NWNUE/view?usp=sharing)) and clicked *Debug as Local C/C++ Application*, the following error is shown:

[image: Debug as Local C/C++ Ap]

Reinstalling Mingw-w64 didn't fix the problem. A sample *Hello World C++ Project* compiles and debugs as expected but for any reason this Project doesn't. Maybe it has to do with the fact that it utilizes the [libxl-3.6.2.0](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1dS7bWX63QZZ0lZNk1VcHJLakk/view?usp=sharing) dll from bin64 folder to read an excel file.

---

**Eclipse configuration:**

Eclipse Mars.1 (4.5.1)

- C/C++ Development Tools                8.8.0.201509131935
- C/C++ GDB Hardware Debugging               8.8.0.201509131935
- C/C++ Library API Documentation Hover Help 4.1.0.201509161915

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging became possible just adding the 64 bits dll inside LibXl folder bin64 to the Debug folder (where the generated executable was created). This solution insight came from [@smurff1975](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279478/smurff1975)'s comment in the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33536614/c-qt-libxl-error-during-startup-program-exited-with-code-0xc0000135/33545758#33545758).