# Pyarrow write nested array to parquet

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow

I want to write a parquet file that has some normal columns with 1d array data and some columns that have nested structure, i.e. 2d arrays.

I have tried the following:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([0, 1, 2], dtype=np.uint8)
array2 = np.array([[0,1,2], [3, 4, 5]], dtype=np.uint8).T

t1 = pa.uint8()
t2 = pa.list_(pa.uint8())

fields = [
    pa.field('a1', t1),
    pa.field('a2', t2)
]

myschema = pa.schema(fields)

mytable = pa.Table.from_arrays([
    pa.array(array1, type=t1),
    pa.array([array2[:,0], array2[:,1]], type=t2)],
    schema=myschema)

pq.write_table(mytable, 'example.parquet')
```

The table creation works as expected. The last line is where the issue lies. It causes the Python interpreted to crash.

On windows Python 3.6.4 64-bit I get the error code:
**EDIT:** using pyarrow 0.11.1

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

I have also tried in Windows Linux (WSL) using a separate install of Python 3.6.5 64-bit and I get:
**EDIT:** using pyarrow 0.12.1

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33582766/process-finished-with-exit-code-1073741515-0xc0000135) suggesting to reinstall Python, but since I've tried with two different installs so far I don't think this will help.

I can't see anything in the PyArrow docs to suggest writing nested arrays to Parquet doesn't work, I know there are [issues with this](https://github.com/dask/fastparquet/issues/272) in fastparquet

Comment: This seems like an issue in `pyarrow`. Can you check that this still persists with the latest 0.12.1 release? If so, please report an issue at https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/ARROW/issues

Comment: Have edited and added pyarrow versions. The test in WSL was with 0.12.1

Comment: Issue created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-4774