# tensorflow session stops when try to print values

Tags: python, tensorflow, session

I have a problem with tesorflow session or python.
Everytime I try to print some tensor values to check the network works well,
the program stops with this error.

> " Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) "

I use `python 3.5` and `tensorflow-gpu 1.14.0` now.

I also tried a very simple code like below, the process stopped without printing any values.
I can't find out what's wrong.
Can anyone help me? Thanks.

```py
input = tf.constant([2, 3, 4])
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(input))
```

I also can see this comment what I've never seen before. Is this the problem?
" GPU libraries are statically linked, skip dlopen check."

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33582766/process-finished-with-exit-code-1073741515-0xc0000135

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by making a new pycharm project.

And the error about GPU, 
"GPU libraries are statically linked, skip dlopen check."

→ I downgraded the tensorflow-gpu version to 1.13.1 because 1.14.0 may not compatiable with CUDA 10.0.