# Android Studio run ADV Emulator Error Windows 10

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator, expo

I have an error when I launch the android emulator. The Android studio version is 3.6. Here is the screenshot.

```
08:38   Gradle sync started
08:38   * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
08:38   * daemon started successfully
08:38   Gradle sync finished in 1 s 859 ms (from cached state)
**08:38 Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)**
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33582766/process-finished-with-exit-code-1073741515-0xc0000135)

Comment: @benoxy in your question can't find the screenshot. do add the error code.

Comment: Improved formatting.