# Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) using PyWavelets on PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pywt

I am get this annoying bug when I try to use the function pywt.cwt on my computer at work (windows64-bit). The code is working fine on my personal mac book.

I am getting this message: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) and the code just stop without python error message.

I trying older version of PyWavelets, to re-install the python interpreter (3.7 and 3.8) and nothing works

Answer (score 1):

reinstall python – you don't have python33.dll in c:\WINDOWS\system32\

Maybe you have different python versions – look at folders in the root of c:

If yes, then point to your version of python.exe in pyCharm > Settings > Project Interpreter

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33582766/process-finished-with-exit-code-1073741515-0xc0000135)

Comment: I already tried to reinstall python. Actually, when I install the PyWavelet library I get this error: ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1. Wit this message: Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at 'C:\Users\I0326129\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe'.

Comment: And there is still not python33.dll file in c:\WINDOWS\system32\, even after re-installation.

Comment: @Stravoguine I think you can try one more by adding dll file https://www.dll-files.com/python33.dll.html

Comment: I add the python33.dll fill, re-install python and I still got the same error.. I guess I will try to re-install pyCharm also