# Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) and python crash

Tags: python-3.x, embedded, python-multithreading

I am using vector manual xl driver dll , I am trying to recieve event from xlrecieve function using RXthread (which is running in background until we close thread)
In between or in end, sometimes I am receiving below error code which crashes the python
error code-
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Pseudo code-

1. RX thread -start
2. wait for event (using waitforsingleobject) in every 10ms
3. check XLrecive function if any event came -if yes send to callback function
4. keep running 1,2,3 step

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33582766/process-finished-with-exit-code-1073741515-0xc0000135

Comment: No @MichaelKotzjan, I tried this but I am getting the same Issue

Comment: The _real_ code is what is crashing, so how do you hope to get an answer by presenting _pseudo code_?  Why is this tagged [embedded]?