# With CMake, how can I set environment properties on the gtest_discover_tests --gtest_list_tests call?

Tags: cmake, googletest

I'm currently working on migrating our current build environment from MSBuild to CMake.  I have a situation where I need to update the `PATH` variable in order for the units tests executable to run.  This is not a issue for `gtest_add_tests`, as it uses the source to identify tests.  But `gtest_discover_tests`, which executes the unit tests with the `--gtest_list_tests` flag, fails to identify any tests because a `STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND` error is encountered during the build.

For example:

```
add_executable(gTestExe ...)
target_include_directories(gTestExe ...)
target_compile_definitions(gTestExe ...)
target_link_libraries(gTestExe ...)
set (NEWPATH "/path/to/bin;$ENV{PATH}")
STRING(REPLACE ";" "\\;" NEWPATH "${NEWPATH}")
```

This works:

```
gtest_add_tests(TARGET gTestExe TEST_LIST allTests)
set_tests_properties(${all_tests} PROPERTIES ENVIRONMENT "PATH=${NEWPATH}")
```

But this does not:

```
#set_target_properties(gTestExe  PROPERTIES ENVIRONMENT "PATH=${NEWPATH}")
#set_property(DIRECTORY PROPERTY ENVIRONMENT "PATH=${NEWPATH}")
gtest_discover_tests(gTestExe  PROPERTIES ENVIRONMENT "PATH=${NEWPATH}")
```

Edit:
The tests themselves work when added using `gtest_add_tests`.  The issue is the call to discover the tests, during the post build step that `gtest_discover_tests` registers, fails because the required libraries are not in the `PATH`.

Comment: Are the tests themselves failing to build because of the missing DLL dependencies? If that is the case, have you seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40042831/3987854)?

Comment: @squareskittles I edited to try to clear up the issue I am seeing.  The tests are building, it is the test discovery step that fails.  Although, I believe some of the solutions described in that link  wold work (copying dlls for example).

Comment: Ok, if you find a solution or workaround that works for you, please post an answer.

Answer (score -1):

I came across the same issue this morning and I found a (dirty ?) workaround. The reason why it won't work is a bit complicated, but the workaround is quite simple.

### Why it won't work

```
gtest_discover_tests(gTestExe  PROPERTIES ENVIRONMENT "PATH=${NEWPATH}")
```

Will not work is because the PATH contents are separated by semicolons and therefore are treated by CMake as a list value.

If you look a the `GoogleTestAddTests.cmake` file (located in `C:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.17\Modules`), it treats the `PROPERTIES` argument with a [foreach](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/command/foreach.html).

The `PROPERTIES` value look like this for CMake at this point in the script : `ENVIRONMENT;PATH=mypath;mypath2` and will treat `mypath2` as a third argument instead of a value for the PATH environment variable.

CMake will then generate the following line :

```
set_tests_properties( mytest PROPERTIES ENVIRONMENT PATH=mypath mypath2)
```

Escaping the `;` won't work because the list is automatically expended in `add_custom_command()` in `GoogleTest.cmake` *(l. 420 in cmake 3.17.1)* ignoring any form of escaping.

To prevent the cmake foreach to treat each value in the path as a list you can use a [bracket argument](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#bracket-argument) like :

```
gtest_discover_tests(gTestExe PROPERTIES ENVIRONMENT "[==[PATH=${NEWPATH}]==]")
```

The cmake foreach will then treat your argument as one entity. Unfortunately CMake will also put a bracket in the generated code as it contains `[` `=` and maybe spaces :

```
# This line 
if(_arg MATCHES "[^-./:a-zA-Z0-9_]")
  set(_args "${_args} [==[${_arg}]==]")
else()
  set(_args "${_args} ${_arg}")
endif()
```

resulting in the following generated script :

```
set_tests_properties( mytest PROPERTIES ENVIRONMENT [==[ [==[PATH=mypath;mypath2] ]==])
```

And when executing the test cmake will attempt to read the value only removing the first [bracket argument](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#bracket-argument) as they don't nest.

### Possible workaround

So to do this we need CMake to not use bracket argument on our own bracket argument.

First make a local copy of `GoogleTestAddTests.cmake` file in your own repository (located in `C:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.17\Modules`).

At the beginning of your local copy of `GoogleTestAddTests.cmake` *(l. 12)* replace the function `add_command` by this one :

```
function(add_command NAME)
  set(_args "")
  foreach(_arg ${ARGN})
    # Patch : allow us to pass a bracket arguments and escape the containing list.
    if (_arg MATCHES "^\\[==\\[.*\\]==\\]$")
        string(REPLACE ";" "\;" _arg "${_arg}")
        set(_args "${_args} ${_arg}")
    # end of patch
    elseif(_arg MATCHES "[^-./:a-zA-Z0-9_]")
        set(_args "${_args} [==[${_arg}]==]")
    else()
        set(_args "${_args} ${_arg}")
    endif()
  endforeach()
  set(script "${script}${NAME}(${_args})\n" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()
```

This will make cmake don't use bracket list on our bracket list and automatically escape the `;` as `set_tests_properties` also treat the `;` as a list.

Finally we need CMake to use our custom `GoogleTestAddTests.cmake` instead of the one in CMake.

After your call to `include(GoogleTest)` set the variable `_GOOGLETEST_DISCOVER_TESTS_SCRIPT` to the path to your local `GoogleTestAddTests.cmake` :

```
# Need google test
include(GoogleTest)

# Use our own version of GoogleTestAddTests.cmake
set(_GOOGLETEST_DISCOVER_TESTS_SCRIPT
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/GoogleTestAddTests.cmake
)
```

*Note : In my example the GoogleTestAddTests.cmake is right next to the processing cmake file.*

Then a simple call to

```
 gtest_discover_tests(my_target
   PROPERTIES ENVIRONMENT "[==[PATH=${my_path};$ENV{PATH}]==]"
 )
```

should work.