# How to view Docker default stdout in Windows 10?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, powershell, docker, dockerfile

I have created an image for a simple DockerConsoleProgram.cc program

this is the Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/nanoserver
COPY DockerConsoleProgram.exe /
CMD ["DockerConsoleProgram.exe"]
```

this is the source:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

    int main() {

        printf("Hello my Docker");

    }
```

When I build the image I do not have any problems. When I launch the container I do not see any output:

[image]

Comment: This answers your question: https://serverfault.com/questions/596994/how-can-i-debug-a-docker-container-initialization

Comment: @SaqibAhmed in your link there is not an answer for my question

Comment: Is there anything in the logs of your container? `docker logs <containername>`

Comment: @jerom987 nothing :-(

Comment: Could you do `docker container ls -a` and check if the container is still running, stopped, or exited with an exit code?

Comment: @jerom987  docker container ls -a ????

Comment: That should return all containers on your system. Added with their state, and if shutdown have their exit code listed too

Comment: @jerom987   Exited (3221225781)

Answer (score 0):

Considering the error code you mentioned in the comments on the question.
Docker returned the decimal error code (`3221225781`), converted to HEX this is error code `0xc000135`.

Googling this code returns: `STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND` (More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432940/what-does-error-code-0xc0000135-mean-when-starting-a-net-application))

This means you're probably just missing the .NET Framework. The easiest solution is to rebuild your application (since you have the source code anyway) and build it as a .NET Core app.[Tutorial here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio)

The nano servers only support .NET Core framework as far as I know. There could be an option to install other frameworks though.