# Error code 0xc0000135 in python sqlalchemy code

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm running some python code that reads a json formatted file and uploads the data to a SQL server table. The code crashes without explanation and simply returns the error code: 0xc0000135. The relevant code is

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://" + dbname + "?driver=SQL+Server", fast_executemany=True)
df.to_sql(tname, engine, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=10)
```

Here's what I've figured out so far:

1) The code is related to the .NET framework (see: [What does error code 0xc0000135 mean when starting a .NET application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432940/what-does-error-code-0xc0000135-mean-when-starting-a-net-application)) and likely means I don't have the right version installed.

2) I have version 4.8 installed.

3) I am using sqlalchemy version 1.3.10

4) I am using python version 3.7.3

I haven't been able to figure out what version of the .Net framework I actually *need* to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was an incompatibility between the driver and the fast_executemany option that occurred only under certain circumstances (possibly the python version, since the same code works on other computers).

The solution was to use driver=ODBC+Driver+13+for+SQL+Server instead of driver=SQL+Server.